# MySQL - How to use the columns alias from subqueries for another sub query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, multiple-columns

```
select name, 
 (select sum(balance) from customers group by name having balance>0 and `type of contract`!="loan") as holdings, 
 (select sum(balance) from customers group by name having balance<0 or `type of contract`="loan") as borrowings, 
 (select case when holdings-borrowings>0 then "positive" else "negative" end from customers) as `positive/negative`, 
 holdings-borrowings as total 
 from customers 
 group by name 
 order by name;
```

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'holdings' in 'field list'.

The table definition is, name varchar, `type of contract` varchar, balance int.
I know where the error is, I can't use the column alias from the subqueries but I don't know how to execute the query in another method.

Comment: Correct solution - convert your query to CTE or subquery. Palliative solution - use user-defined variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below using `conditional aggregation`

**Note:** column alias can not be used as a reference in the projection list that's the reason you got the error

```
select name, 
sum(case when balance>0 and `type of contract`!="loan" then balance else 0 end) as holdings,
sum(case when balance<0 and `type of contract`="loan" then balance else 0 end) as borrowings,
case when (sum(case when balance>0 and `type of contract`!="loan" then balance else 0 end)-
sum(case when balance<0 and `type of contract`="loan" then balance else 0 end))>0 then 'positive' else 'negative' end as `positive/negative`,
sum(case when balance>0 and `type of contract`!="loan" then balance else 0 end)-
sum(case when balance<0 and `type of contract`="loan" then balance else 0 end) as total
from customers   
group by name 
order by name
```

OR -

```
select name, holdings,borrowings,case when holdings-borrowings>0 then 'Postivie' else 'Negative' end as `positive/negative`,holdings-borrowings as total
from
(
select name, 
    sum(case when balance>0 and `type of contract`!="loan" then balance else 0 end) as holdings,
    sum(case when balance<0 and `type of contract`="loan" then balance else 0 end) as borrowings
    from customers   
    group by name
)A order by name
```

Comment: But in holding and borrowings, I need the sum of the balance, not just the balance.

Comment: @NithinGowda, have you executed the query?

Comment: Sorry for commenting prematurely. It works fine. Thank you.

Comment: @NithinGowda, Please don't forget to mark it as accepted answer :)